# Difference between New AsyncCallback(AddressOf Function) AND AddressOf Function

Tags: .net, vb.net

When using the VB .Net asynchronous socket methods, how should the callback functions be defined?

```
Private Sub ServerRunTime(Optional ByRef ListeningAddress As String = "", Optional ByRef Port As Short = 31337)
        Dim Listener As Socket = ConfigListener(ListeningAddress, Port)
        Listener.Listen(32)
        Listener.BeginAccept(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnAccept), Listener)
End Sub

Private Sub OnAccept(ByVal AcceptResult As IAsyncResult)
        Dim Listener As Socket = CType(AcceptResult.AsyncState, Socket)
        Dim aClientObj As New ClientObj
        Dim ClientID As Integer = Clients.Count

        aClientObj.ClientSok = Listener.EndAccept(AcceptResult)
        aClientObj.ClientID = ClientID
        Clients.Add(aClientObj)

        Clients(ClientID).ClientSok.BeginReceive(Clients(ClientID).RecvBuffer, 0, Clients(ClientID).RecvBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, AddressOf OnReceive, ClientID)
        Listener.BeginAccept(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnAccept), Listener)
End Sub
```

In the above code sample I have tested both

```
New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnReceive)
```

AND

```
AddressOf OnReceive
```

and both produce the same result.

So which is correct?
And is it possible to create the AsyncCallback object as a variable to avoid having to create a new one each receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are correct ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b.aspx)):

> The AddressOf operator can be used as the operand of a delegate constructor or it can be used in a context in which the type of the delegate can be determined by the compiler.

- `New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnReceive)`: Here, you use the AddressOf operator as the operand of a delegate constructor.
- `AddressOf OnReceive`: Here, the type of the delegate (`AsyncCallback`) is automatically inferred by the compiler.

The first option is more explicit, the latter one more compact. Which one to use is a matter of taste.

---

About caching the AsyncCallback object: Yes, it's possible, but I really doubt that the performance benefit (if any) is worth the hassle.